# Signing in existing users from Devise registrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm toying with the idea of automatically signing a user in when they try to signup with existing, valid credentials.

So far, I tweaked `Devise::RegistrationsController#create`:

```
def create_method_from_devise_controller
  existing_user = User.find_by_email(sign_up_params[:email])

  if existing_user && existing_user.valid_password?(sign_up_params["password"]) && sign_in(:user, existing_user)
    respond_with existing_user, location: after_sign_in_path_for(existing_user)
  else
    super
  end
end
```

This works fine in my test case but I was wondering if the approach was safe enough.

Perhaps other people have already tried something similar? Perhaps solutions already exist somewhere (this problem is so difficult to Google for)?

Also: are there potential downside with different authentication strategies? I only tried with `rememberable` and `database_authenticable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be to use Warden to authenticate the user just like [`Devise::SessionsController`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb) does. Extracted source:

```
  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
```

`auth_options` returns a hash:

```
{ scope: resource_name, recall: "#{controller_path}#new" }
```

That way you don't duplicate the actual authentication logic. An actual case where this would make a difference is if you are using `confirmable`.

```
existing_user && existing_user.valid_password?(sign_up_params["password"]) && sign_in(:user, existing_user)
```

In your example the duplicated authentication step only considers the password - this would act as a backdoor allowing unconfirmed users access.

Comment: Thanks! That's actually what I was trying in the first place, but got stuck because the controller was missing `allow_params_authentication!`